# Accessing flask app's config gives "module object has no attribute __getitem__"

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to implement email authentication to my flask app where users must confirm their email address upon completely the online registration process. I m guessing maybe it's the way i setup the config in my app.py or i should modify my config.py? Any thoughts?

This is my app.py

```
....
import config

app = Flask(__name__)

# Import configuration
app.config.from_object(config.DevelopmentConfig)

# Initialize extensions
lm = LoginManager()
lm.session_protection = 'strong'
lm.init_app(app)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
moment = Moment(app)
mail = Mail(app)
......
```

This is my token.py

```
from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer
import app


def generate_confirmation_token(email):
    serializer = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    return serializer.dumps(email, salt=app.config['SECRET_PASSWORD_SALT'])

def confirm_token(token, expiration=3600):
    serializer = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    try:
        email = serializer.loads(token, salt=app.config['SECRET_PASSWORD_SALT'], max_age=expiration)
    except:
        return False
    return email
```

This is the error log generated by flask debug

```
TypeError
TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/vagrant/catalog/app/main/routes.py", line 20, in index
token = generate_confirmation_token(user.email)
File "/vagrant/catalog/app/token.py", line 6, in generate_confirmation_token
serializer = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a package named `app`, and import a module named `config`.  The `app` module also defines a variable named `app`, which has an attribute named `config`.  You imported the wrong `app`.

```
from app import app
app.config['SECRET_KEY']
```